# How can I find repos of my GitHub account repos from GitHub Desktop, once a local repo takes all the place in the app?

Tags: github-desktop

I started to use GitHub Desktop, and see some repositories from my GitHub account. Then, once I draw a local GitHub repo to the app, all those repos disappear and I am stuck with the local GitHub and cannot find a way to navigate back. Sound silly I know but how can I find my GitHub account repos?

[image: Screenshot]

If I tried to change "Current Repository" on the left up button, I got an empty list of repositories:

[image]

Comment: I assume you have tried to change the current repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is Clone a different repo that doesn't exist on your machine.  To do that it is under the File > Clone Repository.  You should see a list of your Github repos in a drop down list at that point if you have setup your permissions to properly connect to your account.
Note: I did this on Windows so wording might be slightly different on a Mac, but I assume it will be close enough.